# Julia parallel behavior different in v0.5.0 and v0.6.0?

Tags: julia

I get different behavior for the *same* code below for Julia 0.5.0 and 0.6.0

```
workspace()
rmprocs(workers())

addprocs(2)
r = @spawnat workers()[2] @eval a=20000
println(fetch(r)) # prints 20000 as expected

a = 1 # assign value to a in process 1

r = @spawnat workers()[2] @eval a
println(fetch(r)) # prints 20000 as expected

r = @spawnat(workers()[2], getfield(Main, :a))
println(fetch(r)) # prints 20000 as expected, equivalent to previous fetch

@sync @spawnat workers()[2] println(a) # prints 1 as expected

r = @sync @spawnat workers()[1] @eval a=10000 # define variable a on workers()[1]

@everywhere println(a) # different results on v0.5.0 and v0.6.0
```

The difference is shown below - namely, that `workers()[2]` gets a value of `a` from process 1 which is never explicitly assigned to it. The 0.5.0 code works like I expect it to, and 0.6.0 does not. Any ideas what could be going on here or is it something I don't understand?

```
v0.5                                      v0.6

WARNING: rmprocs: process 1 not removed | WARNING: rmprocs: process 1 not removed
20000                                   | 20000
20000                                   | 20000
20000                                   | 20000
    From worker 3:  1                   |       From worker 3:  1
1                                       | 1
    From worker 2:  10000               |       From worker 2:  10000
    From worker 3:  20000               |       From worker 3:  1
```

Comment: `@spawnat workers()[2] println(a) # prints 1 as expected`. Why is it expected to print 1?

Comment: I suspect that's because `a` is created on process 1 and `println(a)` as a whole is simply evaluated on `workers()[2]`. I think it's akin to doing `remotecall_fetch(2,println,a)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with [global variables in v0.6.0](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/parallel-computing/#Global-variables-1) onwards.

Global constants (in Module Main) are declared as constants on remote nodes too. If I had used a let statement in the above code as follows:

```
let a=a
    @sync @spawnat workers()[2] println(a) # prints 1 as expected
end
```

then 0.5.0 and 0.6.0 produce the same result with the `@everywhere println(a)` on the last line of my previously posted code snippet. I probably need to delve further into channels and futures for parallel code which requires data transfer, initializing variables on parallel processes, etc.